# Open iTerm2 with ctrl+ctrl?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2, iterm

I recently switched from TotalTerminal (formerly Visor) to iTerm2 on Mac OS X. I used to be able to open TotalTerminal with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (two quick taps). Is this same shortcut possible in iTerm2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_ITERM</name>
    <url>file:///Applications/iTerm.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__DoublePressModifier__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L,
    KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_ITERM</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

If you have the Powerpack for Alfred 2, you can create a workflow like this:

[image]

If you want to make the shortcut toggle showing iTerm, add for example `__DoublePressModifier__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L,
    KeyCode::F18` to private.xml and then set F18 as the shortcut for toggling iTerm:

[image]

Or check the "Toggle visibility for apps" option in Alfred.

Comment: Thanks. This opens iTerm if it's not already open, but it won't toggle the visor if it's already open.

Comment: I think it's easier to just use command-H, but I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

iTerm2 **does** now **natively** support this shortcut.

If you don't already have a hotkey window:
Preferences > Keys > Hotkey > Create a dedicated hotkey window.

If you do already have one, go to Profiles > Hotkey (profile name) > Keys > Configure Hotkey window.

Now set "Double-tap key" to `^ Control`. Here you can define additional hotkeys also.

[image: Hotkey profile Keys settings]

You can also configure new tabs to open in the same profile, and any other hotkey window customizations such as sticking to the side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

iTerm2 does not natively support this option, nor does the System Preferences keyboard prefpane. Search results show no programs capable of replicating such keyboard shortcut functionality. Your best bet is to get something like Quicksilver or Alfred and use control-control (or any other such key tap sequence you desire) to open the launcher app, then type the first few letters of "iTerm" and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Alfreds Powerpack and create a new Workflow. Use a Trigger for double CTRL and an Apple Script as Action.

The Applescript should look like this

```
on alfred_script(q)

    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "^" using control down

end alfred_script
```

Enable "Cache compiled AppleScript" for maximum performance.

[image: Alfred Workflow]